# Can't Center AND inline in the header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i just started css & html this week, but i already have a problem with the top-bar.
I don't understand why the elements of my top-bar won't align and be center.

```
<!--HEADER-->

<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
...
<!-- END OF LOGIN FORM -->

<!-- END OF HEADER -->
```

I want them to be align and straight, like

> [LOGO] [h1] [LOGIN_FORM]

And i might add some buttons in the futur.

(PS: I use Bootstrap 3)

/!\EDIT/!\ :

I fixed some trouble and make my code a bit cleaner, but style doesn't work :(

```
<body>
<!-- TOP BAR --> 
<img src="../images/company-logo.png"/> <h1
id="text-center" style="display:inline"> NetStatus </h1> 
<!-- LOGIN FORM -->
....
```

[image: Actual display TOPBAR]

I just need "NetStatus" to be center

Comment: <center>` is an obsolute element and shoudn't be used.

Comment: Also you can't put a `form` in the `head` tag. You have a great deal wrong with your code. **Validate**

Comment: Did you mean to write `<header>` because the `<head>` tag is only for document-related data and links, no presentational code should be placed there, for that you have the `<body>`. Since you are using Bootstrap you could just add the class `text-center` to your nav container. https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/unmktuva/

Comment: first don't use center tag for this perpous use text-align:center and second never put form in head tag it's not standard

Comment: and exactly what do u want? h4 in center ? or hole header?

Comment: I Want logo on left, h1 in center and login form on right, but evrytime i try to center h1, evrything start to move and it's not align anymore

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score -1):

use text-align: center and that will center your text

Comment: I try like that : 
<!-- TOP BAR -->
<img src="../images/company-logo.png"/>
<h1 id="text-center"> NetStatus </h1>

<!-- LOGIN FORM -->

Comment: now it's display like : [LOGO] \n [h1] ... [LOGIN FORM] (right)

Comment: class="text-center" not id="text-center"

Comment: @sgr0691 help pls ;_;

Comment: @varunraja Didn't change anything

Comment: @superzero10 you can also use padding to center the text

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to justify such a basic and vague answer. If there are any block-level elements, `text-align` will have zero effect...